# ORDER BY with zero values ordered differently

Tags: sqlite, select, sql-order-by

I want to add a temporary column call RowNum (I have succeed in getting it).
But my problem is that I want my data to be ordered > or < with zero values at the end in my column 'Moyenne'.
I can't write it in the last ORDER BY because I want my table order by RowNum.

```
     SELECT 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orieps AS t2 
    WHERE (t2.Nbparcours > t1.Nbparcours ) 
    OR (t2.Nbparcours = t1.Nbparcours AND t2.Nberreurs < t1.Nberreurs  ) 
    OR (t2.Nbparcours = t1.Nbparcours AND t2.Nberreurs = t1.Nberreurs AND t2.Moyenne < t1.Moyenne  ) ) +1 
AS rowNum, Nom, Nbparcours, Nberreurs, Moyenne, Total , P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 
FROM  orieps t1 
    ORDER BY  RowNum ASC
```

Here is my table orieps:

```
   Nbparcours|Nberreurs|Moyenne
        1    |    1    |   0
        1    |    1    |  3.5
        2    |    1    |   3
```

And this is what I want:

```
 ROwNum|Nbparcours|Nberreurs|Moyenne
    1  |    2     |    1    |   3
    2  |    1     |    1    |  3.5
    3  |    1     |    1    |   0
```

First Order by Nbparcours, if equal then order by Nberreurs if equal then order by Moyenne but 0 last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the value `0` to behave as if it were a large number.

So replace

```
... AND t2.Moyenne < t1.Moyenne
```

with [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case)s to map `0` to a different value:

```
... AND CASE t2.Moyenne WHEN 0 THEN 'last' ELSE t2.Moyenne END
      < CASE t1.Moyenne WHEN 0 THEN 'last' ELSE t1.Moyenne END
```

(In SQLite, numbers compare smaller than any string.)

Comment: You are a genius!! Thanks!! I didn't know about CASE (i am a beginner in Sqlite) It works very well! Thanks again